# Limit code execution time

Tags: php

I've a script that sends requests to a remote server every 3 seconds and grabs JSON data.

Recently  our workload got much bigger and now the script has to make multiple requests every 3 seconds.

The problem is some requests takes too long to execute on the remote server and timed out so the script has to wait 1 minute ( max timeout ) to continue making other requests. On the other hand front end users are waiting for updates.

Here is an example.

```
foreach($all as $one){

$result = sendRemoteRequest($parameter); //usually takes only miliseconds to complete but sometimes up to a minute.

}
```

How do I set a timeout for  `$result = sendRemoteRequest($parameter);` execution time?

Comment: If you use curl on your sendRomoteRequest you can use : curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
if not you can edit the php execution time using set_time_limit()

Comment: We have no idea how your function `sendRemoteRequest` works, so we can not possibly answer that question.